# Write the solution set as a span of four vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> Write the solution set of $$2x+3y-3z+w+v=0$$ as a span of four vectors (i.e. find four vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$ so that their span in $\mathbb{R}^5$ is the solution set of this equation).

I'm having trouble with this problem.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x = t_1$, $y = t_2$, $z = t_3$, $w= t_4$. Then, $v = -2t_1 -3t_2 + 3t_3 - t_4$. 
So solution $$(x, y, z, w, v) = (t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, -2t_1 -3t_2 + 3t_3 - t_4)$$ 
$$= t_1(1, 0, 0, 0, -2) + t_2(0, 1, 0, 0, -3) + t_3(0, 0, 1, 0, 3) + t_4(0, 0, 0, 1, -1)$$

Here choice of $t_1, \cdots, t_4$ is arbitrary. thus, solution space is span of the four vectors, $$\operatorname{spa}n\{(1, 0, 0, 0, -2), (0, 1, 0, 0, -3), (0, 0, 1, 0, 3), (0, 0, 0, 1, -1)\}.$$

Comment: And note that the four vectors are orthogonal to the vector $(2, 3, -3, 1,1)$. In fact this problem is a problem finding four vectors which is orthogonal to the given vector in $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the solution set as having four free variables (let's say $y,z,w,v$) and one bound variable ($x$).  The solution is a four-dimensional vector space, and to find a basis you can just set each free variable to 1 in turn, and the others to zero.  The bound variable(s),  namely $x$, are calculated from the free variables.  This approach gives:

$$(-3/2,1,0,0,0), (3/2,0,1,0,0), (-1/2,0,0,1,0), (-1/2,0,0,0,1)$$